# Validate Uniqueness of a Relation in Neo4jrb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

Es posible tener un "validate_uniqueness_of" de una relación con la gema neo4jrb? . Ej: Tengo un modelo THING con su respectivo HAS_ONE de otro modelo llamado LOCATION. Pero ahora mismo ese THING puede tener más de un LOCATION..

Alguien sabe porque ocurre?
Se puede validar que solo tenga uno? o debería hacer algo así como un callback

Gracias

Comment: Hola William, este sitio es en Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Editado a español